# How do I write map that works for all types in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift2

As an exercise, I'm implementing a map function that takes an array and a function and applies the function to all elements of the array, but I don't know how to declare it such that it works for any type of array.
I can do something like

```
func intMap(var arr: [Int], fun: (Int) -> Int) -> [Int] {
    for i in 0 ..< arr.count {
        arr[i] = fun(arr[i])
    }
    return arr
}

intMap([1,2,3], {x in return x * x})
```

But this only works for int.

What is the type signature for Swift's built-in map?

*Edit:*

So I was missing the fact that I can declare param type signatures without declaring their types explicitly.

```
func myMap<T>(var arr: [T], fun: (T) -> T) -> [T] {
    for i in 0 ..< arr.count {
        arr[i] = fun(arr[i])
    }
    return arr
}

myMap([1,2,3], fun: {
    x in return x * x
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Create a new Playground
- Just under where it has `import UIKit` type `import Swift`
- Command click on the word **Swift**

This will open the Swift library and you can see all the type definitions there.

And you can see:

```
extension CollectionType {
/// Return an `Array` containing the results of mapping `transform`
/// over `self`.
///
/// - Complexity: O(N).
@warn_unused_result
@rethrows public func map<T>(@noescape transform: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> T) rethrows -> [T]
```

**Edited to add**

Alternatively, you can write a more generalised map

```
func myMap<T, U>(var arr: [T], fun: T -> U) -> [U] {
    var a: [U] = []
    for i in 0 ..< arr.count {
        a.append(fun(arr[i]))
    }

    return a
}
```

Which returns a new array, of a possibly different type, which you can see for yourself by putting this in your playground.

```
let a = [1, 2, 3]
let b = myMap(a, fun: { x in Double(x) * 2.1 })
a
b
```

Comment: How wonderful. So U could be T or could be an altogether different type.